# Rotational Invariance of the Bell State

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In this lecture P[v] is stated to be: $$\cos^2 \theta$$ In view my P[v] should be: $$ \frac{\pi - \theta} {\pi} $$

Can some one please confirm my claim or explain where the $\cos^2 \theta$ comes from?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivmThsbkhTU

Comment: Why do you think it should be $1-\theta$? It would also be helpful if you could explain what $P$ and $\theta$ were so that people do not have to sit through a video to answer your question

Comment: Actually I think the P[v] should be (pi - theta) / pi not 1 - theta. P[v] is the probability of measuring state v and theta is the angle of rotation of the basis.

Comment: $P(a,b)=\frac {1}{2}sin^2(\theta_{ab}/2)$. No I didn't watch the video.

Answer (score 0):

I’m trying to understand this topic too. So far my understanding is this:

If angle is chosen in advance, completely at random, then probability of measuring same direction on two different basises is (π-θ)/π.

But if there is a quantum mechanics involved, then measuring first photon “skewes” the distribution for the second one, and probability for correlation changes to cos²θ.

Measuring the difference between (π-θ)/π and cos²θ is the whole point of CHSH experiment. The act of “skewing” by merely measuring is that “spooky action at distance” that everybody talks about.

Illustration:

[image]

Illustration source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unb_yoj1Usk